# Display selected tab item into url path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to display selected tab item into url path. I found this Material UI example:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Tabs from '@mui/material/Tabs';
import Tab from '@mui/material/Tab';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

interface TabPanelProps {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  index: number;
  value: number;
}

function TabPanel(props: TabPanelProps) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`vertical-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`vertical-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && (
        <Box sx={{ p: 3 }}>
          <Typography>{children}</Typography>
        </Box>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

function a11yProps(index: number) {
  return {
    id: `vertical-tab-${index}`,
    'aria-controls': `vertical-tabpanel-${index}`,
  };
}

export default function VerticalTabs() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent, newValue: number) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{ flexGrow: 1, bgcolor: 'background.paper', display: 'flex', height: 224 }}
    >
      <Tabs
        orientation="vertical"
        variant="scrollable"
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        aria-label="Vertical tabs example"
        sx={{ borderRight: 1, borderColor: 'divider' }}
      >
        <Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} />
        <Tab label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)} />
        <Tab label="Item Three" {...a11yProps(2)} />
        <Tab label="Item Four" {...a11yProps(3)} />
        <Tab label="Item Five" {...a11yProps(4)} />
        <Tab label="Item Six" {...a11yProps(5)} />
        <Tab label="Item Seven" {...a11yProps(6)} />
      </Tabs>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        Item One
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        Item Two
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
        Item Three
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={3}>
        Item Four
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={4}>
        Item Five
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={5}>
        Item Six
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={6}>
        Item Seven
      </TabPanel>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

https://mui.com/components/tabs/#VerticalTabs.tsx

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/verticaltabs-material-demo-forked-yyqhm

I found this code example how to add url param:
https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting

Do know how I can implement the code to display selected tab into url link. Example: `https://yyqhm.csb.app/<selected_tab>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Main Solution

Check [this solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/verticaltabs-material-demo-forked-y55nq?file=/demo.tsx) out.

It utilizes *react-router-dom*, so wrap your root component with `BrowserRouter`

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Demo />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </StyledEngineProvider>,
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

This is the updated code - the basic idea is to use pathname as the value to check for, and update it when a tab gets picked:

```
import { Routes, Route, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function VerticalTabs() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent, newValue: number) => {
    navigate(newValue);
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        flexGrow: 1,
        bgcolor: "background.paper",
        display: "flex",
        height: 224
      }}
    >
      <Tabs
        orientation="vertical"
        variant="scrollable"
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={
          window.location.pathname == "/"
            ? "/item_one"
            : window.location.pathname
        }
        aria-label="Vertical tabs example"
        sx={{ borderRight: 1, borderColor: "divider" }}
      >
        <Tab value="/item_one" label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} />
        <Tab value="/item_two" label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)} />
        <Tab value="/item_three" label="Item Three" {...a11yProps(2)} />
      </Tabs>

      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={
            <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
              Item One
            </TabPanel>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/item_one"
          element={
            <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
              Item One
            </TabPanel>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/item_two"
          element={
            <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
              Item Two
            </TabPanel>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/item_three"
          element={
            <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
              Item Three
            </TabPanel>
          }
        />
      </Routes>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

### Alternative

Here is a link to the working version of [the code](https://codesandbox.io/s/verticaltabs-material-demo-forked-7kc05?file=/demo.tsx).

The code below reads the pathname of the current page, then sets it to `state`.

```js
...
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setValue( +window.location.pathname.substring(1) );
  }, []);
```

You could also define a dictionary that functions as a sort of inverted index to match custom pathnames to their related index value, or maybe a typescript enum.

```js
{
  'item-one': 1,
  'item-two': 2,
  'item-three': 3,
  1: 'item-one',
  2: 'item-two',
  3: 'item-three'
}
```

Whenever a tab is selected, you can set the index to the path by manipulating `history`.

```js
  const handleChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent, newValue: number) => {
    window.history.replaceState({}, "", "/" + newValue);
    setValue(newValue);
  };
...
```